# using and installing rubyonrails

Tags: ruby, rails

i need help here. i am new to programming and interested in learning rubyonrails.
i installed the above mentioned software on ubuntu 12.10 using i found on ubuntu community page.
after installation, i tried to run the command rake db:migrate, and i got the following errors please help.

```
luke@luke-pc:~/www/railsapp$ rake db:migrate
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /home/luke/www/railsapp/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#initialize is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#initialize called from /home/luke/www/railsapp/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:100.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
rake aborted!
ERROR: 'rake/rdoctask' is obsolete and no longer supported. Use 'rdoc/task' (available in RDoc 2.4.2+) instead.
/home/luke/www/railsapp/Rakefile:8:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117114/error-rake-rdoctask-is-obsolete-and-no-longer-supported-use-rdoc-task-ava

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there are two obsolete gems(?) called in this example. `Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec` and `rake/rdoctask`.

If `rake` is replaced with `rdoc/task`, I think it will correct the problem.

Our problem (I ran into the same thing trying to run a book example) is how to go about replacing the rake function with rdoc. Can you just drop rdoc in in place of rake? May be worth a try; but, I haven't got around to it yet.

I was going to try to research the rdoc first when I came across your question. Hope somebody with the answer pops in but I thought you'd like to know at least someone else is working on it.

Answer (score 0):

After more work, it looks like all that print out is not errors but rather informational.

Deprecation is making a command go away or phase out, in this case in the future (2011-11-1, the future of the version of rails we're running.)

Running some examples from 'Learning Rails' I find that I get all the warnings about deprecation, but the programs **DO** what they're supposed to do. Directories and files are created, etc.

The printouts are warnings that with versions of rails released after the date 2011-11-1 the deprecated will be non-functional and they give suggestions of how to replace the functionality.

In other words, go ahead and run your examples from the book, they'll probably work as long as your software versions aren't too new.

Elsewise, move up to rails 3 and avoid all the useless deprecation warnings (and good luck in finding the real error messages in all that warning printout.)

Also, upgrade your tutorials to rails 3